# Move and copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, copy-elision, nrvo

```
#include <iostream>

class studant {
    public:
    studant () {
        std::cout<<"studant"<<std::endl;
    }
    studant(const  studant& a) {
        std::cout<<"copy studant (&)"<<std::endl;
    }
   studant(studant&& a) {
        std::cout<<"move studant (&)"<<std::endl;
    }
    studant maximum () {
        studant c1;
        return c1;
    }
};
studant create () {
     studant c1;
    return c1;
}
int main()
{
    studant c2;
    studant c3=c2.maximum ();
    studant c4=create ();
}
```

please see the above code why "studant c3=c2.maximum ()"  and  "studant c4=create ()" is not call the copy or move constructor. please explain me.

Comment: You have already tagged the answer yourself: [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which the compiler will apply when returning an object by value whenever possible.

Comment: @PaulSanders the tag was added by the edit of David.

Comment: @t.niese OK, sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the RVO (Return Value Optimization). `studant c3=c2.maximum ()` calls `maximum()`, the compiler knows the `c1` inside `maximum()` will be returned and then assigned to `c3`, and then `c1` will discarded. The compiler is smart enough to create just one instance of `studant` to avoid the assignment. That means `c1` inside `maximum()` is the same instance as `c3`.

This is same for 'c4' and `c1` in function 'create()'.

Comment: This is a correct answer of why this would happen if optimizations are enabled.

Comment: @NadavS For future readers: on a conforming C++17 compiler, RVO occurs regardless of whether optimization are enabled.